# android DatePickerDialog switch place between day and month

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

I have to show a DatePickerDialog dialog and I need to show day, month and year, but on my phone month appears before day. Is there a way to switch places between month and day?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because not everyone is in the US

Answer (score 1):

In settings under Date and time there is an option to change the date format. This should change the DatePickerDialog layout. I have not tested this myself, so please confirm if that is the case.

Comment: But I don't want to change date format settings... just a layout of a dialog

Comment: The DatePickerDialog follows the users setting for a good reason, whatever the user has selected there is the format the user expects the date format to be. If you have your mind set on dictating the format I suggets looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog and creating your own. I do not believe there is any way to change the layout of the existing DatePickerDialog, atleast not one that will work better than building your own AlertDialog with 3 comboboxes

Comment: I tested it on my phone. I changed the date format to year/month/day, but the DatePickerdialog hasn't changed.

Comment: Just tested this on my Nexus 4 running stock 4.2. It works! After changing the date format setting, the datepickerdialog adjusts accordingly, and does it even without me needing to restart my app. It works both for all 3 date formats that I've  tried. For some reason my phone had a non-regional setting, so this solves this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't set the order of pickers in DatePickerDialog according to programmatically set format, because DatePicker which is used in DatePickerDialog takes no fotmat as parameter, but retrieves it from system.

The only things you could do are:
1) create your own dialog
2) set system datetime format when app starts (and maybe restore when application closes)

[android.app.DatePickerDialog src](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java)